# javac crashes when compiling codes with java 1.8 features: Flow$AbstractAssignAnalyzer.visitIdent(Flow.java:2380)

Tags: java, java-8, javac

Recently I upgraded my java codes to 1.8 and applied many 1.8 features (lambda, stream, etc). They can be run properly under Eclipse but failed to be built by maven because javac always threw the following exception:

```
[INFO] Compiling 38 source files to /root/chess-wizard-base/target/classes

An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_25). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$AbstractAssignAnalyzer.visitIdent(Flow.java:2380)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCIdent.accept(JCTree.java:2011)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$BaseAnalyzer.scan(Flow.java:398)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$AbstractAssignAnalyzer.scan(Flow.java:1376)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.visitReference(TreeScanner.java:268)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMemberReference.accept(JCTree.java:1973)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$BaseAnalyzer.scan(Flow.java:398)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$AbstractAssignAnalyzer.scan(Flow.java:1376)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$AbstractAssignAnalyzer.scanExpr(Flow.java:1627)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$AbstractAssignAnalyzer.scanExprs(Flow.java:1639)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$AbstractAssignAnalyzer.visitNewClass(Flow.java:2241)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCNewClass.accept(JCTree.java:1516)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$BaseAnalyzer.scan(Flow.java:398)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$AbstractAssignAnalyzer.scan(Flow.java:1376)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$AbstractAssignAnalyzer.analyzeTree(Flow.java:2423)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$AbstractAssignAnalyzer.analyzeTree(Flow.java:2406)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow.analyzeLambdaThrownTypes(Flow.java:250)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitLambda(Attr.java:2423)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLambda.accept(JCTree.java:1624)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:607)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$2.complete(DeferredAttr.java:284)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$DeferredType.check(DeferredAttr.java:245)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$DeferredType.check(DeferredAttr.java:232)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve$MethodResultInfo.check(Resolve.java:993)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve$4.checkArg(Resolve.java:826)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve$AbstractMethodCheck.argumentsAcceptable(Resolve.java:731)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve$4.argumentsAcceptable(Resolve.java:835)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Infer.instantiateMethod(Infer.java:162)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.rawInstantiate(Resolve.java:564)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.checkMethod(Resolve.java:601)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkMethod(Attr.java:3809)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkIdInternal(Attr.java:3615)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkMethodIdInternal(Attr.java:3522)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkMethodId(Attr.java:3501)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkId(Attr.java:3488)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitNewClass(Attr.java:2074)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCNewClass.accept(JCTree.java:1516)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:607)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribExpr(Attr.java:649)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitVarDef(Attr.java:1093)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCVariableDecl.accept(JCTree.java:852)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:607)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStat(Attr.java:676)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClassBody(Attr.java:4342)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClass(Attr.java:4252)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClass(Attr.java:4181)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attrib(Attr.java:4156)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.attribute(JavaCompiler.java:1248)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile2(JavaCompiler.java:901)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:860)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:785)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:12 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-11-17T18:26:49+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/51M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project chess-wizard-base: Compilation failure
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I have not found out the java class that makes javac crash so far. Now the project to be built by maven is pushed onto github: https://github.com/xqbase/chess-wizard-base.git .

Should I report this issue into Java Developer Connection ?

Comment: Don't report it. Here's your issue: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8059511

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, but they seem not the same stack trace. And codes in JDK-8059511 have a syntax error but my codes have not (compiled by ECJ is ok).

Comment: The NPE happens at the same line of code and the traces even match a few calls deep. That makes it highly likely to be the same bug. Feel free to disagree and to report this as a distinct problem (you may be right, after all).

Comment: You are not right about the syntax error, though. There's a *type* error, which is a whole different thing as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: I might find another java maven compiler plugin. But the eclipse compiler "plexus-compiler-eclipse" does not support jdk 1.8 so far :-(

Comment: Don't bother searching---there's only two Java compilers out there.

Comment: I made the third, see https://github.com/xqbase/compiler-eclipse :-)

Comment: I misunderstood your comment---yes, that's a Maven plugin which uses a newer version of the JDT compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**plexus-compiler-eclipse 2.5** supports jdk 1.8 now. Add the maven compiler plugin into pom:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>
                <optimize>true</optimize>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>plexus-compiler-eclipse</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

Before the javac problem solves or plexus-compiler-eclipse supports jdk 1.8, use xqbase-compiler-eclipse as a workaround to pass maven compilation:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>
                <optimize>true</optimize>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.xqbase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xqbase-compiler-eclipse</artifactId>
                    <version>0.1.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This plugin is pushed into https://github.com/xqbase/compiler-eclipse

Comment: That is GREAT! I can't believe there's so few people interested in having a maven plugin for ECJ supporting Java 8... Keep us updated when you'll take it away. Thanks again!